# What this template syntax "typename = T" mean?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

Sometimes I see syntax like this.

```cpp
template<typename T,typename = int>
int foo(){
    //...
}
```

what part `typename = int` mean?
Where it can be used?

Comment: Just like functions can have default arguments, template arguments can have default types. Also like function arguments doesn't have to be named, template arguments doesn't have to be named.

Comment: So this second typename is relating to  the first typename that has name "T"?

Comment: No, `T` and the unnamed "anonymous" type (that defaults to `int`) are unrelated.

Comment: But if second "anonymous" type is unnamed then what the reason of this syntax? If it is unnamed how i can use this? Can you give a example where there is a reason to use this syntax? I can understand when there is a unnamed type in function declaration but then you should define this function. Can i define template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foo` has two template arguments. The first is called `T` and the second is unnamed and defaults to `int`.

In your piece of code alone there is no reason to use the second argument. Unnamed template arguments often come up with SFINAE. An example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae):

```
// primary template handles non-referenceable types:
template<class T, class = void>
struct reference_traits {
    using add_lref = T;
    using add_rref = T;
};
 
// specialization recognizes referenceable types:
template<class T>
struct reference_traits<T, std::void_t<T&>> {
    using add_lref = T&;
    using add_rref = T&&;
};
 
template<class T>
using add_lvalue_reference_t = typename reference_traits<T>::add_lref;
 
template<class T>
using add_rvalue_reference_t = typename reference_traits<T>::add_rref;
```

The only reason for the primary template to have a second argument is that it can be specialized. When possible the more specialized specialization is instantiatied. If this fails (because `T&` is not valid) then "substitution failure is not an error" (SFINAE) kicks in and the primary template is instantiated instead.

---

A simpler example of unnamed argument is when you want a template argument merely as a tag to distinguish different instantiations:

```
template<typename = int>
struct bar {
    // ...
};
```

Even if the implementation of `bar` does not depend on the template argument you might want to have `bar<double>` and `bar<std::string>` be two distinct types.

Answer (score 3):

this is rarely used ...

but this is the default value for the typename but you don't need it here because the compiler itself can overload the function automatically and get the right type for the right arguments you passed !

also it type for what typename ? it's not makes sense here !

it used when you are using  nested template ...

I found out in the original reference for C++ :

> The template parameter lists of template template parameters can have
> their own default arguments, which are only in effect where the
> template template parameter itself is in scope:
>
> ```
> // class template, with a type template parameter with a default
> template<typename T = float> struct B {};
>  
> // template template parameter T has a parameter list, which 
> // consists of one type template parameter with a default
> template<template<typename = float> typename T> struct A
> {
>     void f();
>     void g();
> };
>  
> // out-of-body member function template definitions
> template<template<typename TT> class T>
> void A<T>::f()
> {
>     T<> t; // error: TT has no default in scope
> }
> template<template<typename TT = char> class T>
> void A<T>::g()
> {
>     T<> t; // ok: t is T<char>
> }
> ```

[this is the link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters)