# How to infer the template parameter from instantiation of function template?

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates

I know how to infer the template parameter from an instantiation of a class template:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo {};

template <typename T>
struct foo_param;

template <typename T>
struct foo_param< foo<T> > {
    using type = T;
};
```

But I am lost at doing the same for a function template. The naive

```
template <typename T>
void bar() {}

template <auto F>
struct bar_param;

template <typename T>
struct bar_param< &bar<T> > {
    using type = T;
};
```

fails with

```
<source>:21:19: error: template argument '& bar<T>' involves template parameter(s)
   21 | struct bar_param< &bar<T> > {
      |                   ^~~~~~~
```

I think I do understand the error (actually it turned out that I didn't but thats a case for a different question), but I don't know how to avoid it. How can I infer eg `int` given a `&bar<int>` ?

Comment: Interestingly, I've never needed to do this ever before. What's the purpose? I would wager it's impossible in general though.

Comment: @PasserBy I have to admit I don't have a use-case at hand. It was triggered by this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/65491395/4117728. In my answer I first wrote "you cannot use the unnamed template parameter", then I realized that it can be infered, then I realized that I don't know how to infer it in case of a function template

Comment: *"I do understand the error"*, Not me ;-)

Comment: Notice that gcc rejects  wrongly example from [temp.class.spec#match-3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4618/temp.class.spec#match-3) with same error message [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eeezhq).

Comment: @Jarod42 to be honest I didnt understand the error ;). It was my way of saying, "don't pay too much attention to it, I need something else". In the mean time I think the problem is that `&bar<T>`s type depends on `T` (even when actually it does not). Clangs error message is much more meaningful https://godbolt.org/z/3YvEx1

Comment: Error from msvc *"explicit specialization is using partial specialization syntax, use template <> instead"* is not helpful neither. We want partial specialization...

Comment: As I comment in answer, with full specialization, it [works](https://godbolt.org/z/WWhrs9). I think issue is that from function pointer value, we can't know if it is coming from `bar<T>` and neither deduce `T`.

Comment: @Jarod42 fwiw this fails with same error and it is more intuitive why it cannot work https://godbolt.org/z/qanr9z

Comment: Issue, is that gcc rejects valid code with same error. So harder to rely on compiler we know is partially bugged about that kind of code.

Comment: @Jarod42 right, but the others reject with their respective same error, was my mistake to pick gcc for the link. Maybe I'll write a language lawyer question later, already getting warnings too much discussion in comments ;)

Comment: In `g<T>::value`, `T` is clearly non deducible. for `&bar<T>`, it *"seems"* deducible, but I think it is not neither (didn't succeed to find that information though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible what do you want.

Not passing through the type of the function, at least, because the type of `bar<T>` is exactly the same for every type: a returning `void` function with no-argumens.

You can verify this with a simple `static_assert()`

```
static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(bar<int>), decltype(bar<long>)> );
```

Comment: I knew I was overlooking something, just expected it to go in the opposite direction ;)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 - yes... is an intriguing question.

Comment: pointers to instantiations are different, so testing for a specific type or a set of types can be done, but thats rather limited

Comment: Issue is "just" the partial specialization, with full specialization, [it works](https://godbolt.org/z/WWhrs9). Non-type template parameters have stricter rules than type template parameters, but I fail to find the one it violates here :-/